# Scaffold-DbContext не создаёт классы для таблиц

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

[image: Таблицы]

Есть 2 таблицы в бд, но такой командой не создаются классы для этих таблиц, создаётся только контекст, может неправильная команда?

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

Comment: `Database=master` - таблицы действительно в master?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ,  да они в master

Comment: master - служебная БД, в которой Sql Server содержит собственную информацию, необходимую для его работы. В ней не должно быть ваших таблиц. Возможно, проблема из-за этого. Создайте пользовательскую БД и перенесите свои таблицы в неё.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, теперь он мне говорит такое: ```Cannot open database "TestDB" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'LAPTOP-O7VCISKL\Vincent'```

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov А, не всё я не к тому серверу подключался, странно, что у меня есть localdb и сервер с названием моего пк

Comment: LocalDB устанавливается одновременно с установкой Visual Studio. Сервер с именем - вероятно, вы устанавливали дополнительно полноценный Sql Server (Express). Management Studio ставили? Ну, вот.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, а, даже так, понятно